# configuring boltCMS with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, bolt-cms

I was trying to get my boltCMS to work with mysql and i had the following changed in the setup file , from:

```
# If you're trying out Bolt, just keep it set to SQLite for now.
database:
    driver: sqlite
    databasename: bolt
```

I changed the above to:

```
database:
    driver: mysql
    databasename: bolt
    username: root
    password: ''
```

now i get the following error:

Bolt - Fatal Error
There is no password set for the database connection, and you're using user 'root'.
That must surely be a mistake, right? Bolt will stubbornly refuse to run until you've set a password for 'root'.

> This is a fatal error. Please fix the error, and refresh the page.
>   Bolt can not run, until this error has been corrected. 
>       Make sure you've read the instructions in the documentation for help. If you can't get it to work, post a message on our forum, and
>   we'll try to help you out. Be sure to include the exact error message
>   you're getting!

I also read this article **[HERE](https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/bolt/mysql-configuration)**

I followed the steps, yet i am getting this error, can somebody help me out please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you set a password for root?

Comment: @JayBlanchard no jay , i have''t :/

Comment: Then set one and your problems will be over.

Answer (score 0):

1. See this tutorial which talk about how installing and configuring correctly
   MySQL https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu
2. it's recommended remove all cache file by hand; all cache file is located in `app/cache`
3. go to your PHPMyadmin and make an empty database, the name of database must match the current value defined in your `app/config/config.yml`
4. then run your site